# Incorporate Frustum culling in ROS PCL-1.5

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-fuerte, pcl-1.7, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using PCL which is part of my ROS Fuerte for my applications. The PCL version I have is 1.5 ...

I saw the [Frustum culling](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_frustum_culling.html) in filters module. Also it seems to be part of PCL-1.7

I checked my include folders and I dont have any files of frustum culling. Should I upgrade my PCL version of ROS or can I incorporate it in the currentt 1.5 version itself ?

If I have to upgrade, How should I proceed with the upgradation of PCL in ROS Fuerte?? Can anyone provide the steps ??

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61671/incorporate-frustum-culling-in-ros-pcl-1.5/) by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned by tfoote, PCL 1.7 is not yet released. However, there is the "trunk version" of PCL which is not yet considered stable and mature, but will eventually become PCL 1.7.

If you want to use the trunk version, the easiest way is to install it alongside PCL version 1.5 which you already have. See the package provided at http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17 which checks out and compiles the current trunk version. You can then use either the ROS PCL (1.5) residing in the pcl namespace or use PCL trunk (pcl17 namespace).

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2